# How to calculate difference between date column and current date?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to calculate the Date Diff between a column field and current date of the system.

Here is my sample code where I have hard coded the my column field with  20170126.

```
val currentDate = java.time.LocalDate.now
var datediff = spark.sqlContext.sql("""Select  datediff(to_date('$currentDate'),to_date(DATE_FORMAT(CAST(unix_timestamp( cast('20170126' as String), 'yyyyMMdd') AS TIMESTAMP), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))) AS  GAP
        """)
datediff.show()

Output is like:
+----+
| GAP|
+----+
|null|
+----+
```

I need to calculate actual Gap Between the two dates but getting `NULL`.

Comment: You are getting null not from the datediff function but your date conversion. . Plus you can use spark-sql's current_date function instead of java.time.LocalDate.now

Comment: Thanks for the advice ..  Am able to resolve this by adding s before the statement which is used for passing a variable to the query :)

Comment: You can write your solution and accept it then. I'll gladly upvote it. And by the way, adding that 's' is called string interpolation. Try to look it up !

Answer (score 3):

You have not defined the type and format of "column field" so I assume it's a string in the (not-very-pleasant) format `YYYYMMdd`.

```
val records = Seq((0, "20170126")).toDF("id", "date")

scala> records.show
+---+--------+
| id|    date|
+---+--------+
|  0|20170126|
+---+--------+

scala> records
  .withColumn("year", substring($"date", 0, 4))
  .withColumn("month", substring($"date", 5, 2))
  .withColumn("day", substring($"date", 7, 2))
  .withColumn("d", concat_ws("-", $"year", $"month", $"day"))
  .select($"id", $"d" cast "date")
  .withColumn("datediff", datediff(current_date(), $"d"))
  .show
+---+----------+--------+
| id|         d|datediff|
+---+----------+--------+
|  0|2017-01-26|      83|
+---+----------+--------+
```

**PROTIP**: Read up on [functions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) object.

### Caveats

#### cast

Please note that I could not convince Spark SQL to `cast` the column "date" to `DateType` given the rules in [DateTimeUtils.stringToDate](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/util/DateTimeUtils.scala#L430-L435):

> - `yyyy`,
> - `yyyy-[m]m`
> - `yyyy-[m]m-[d]d`
> - `yyyy-[m]m-[d]d`
> - `yyyy-[m]m-[d]d *`
> - `yyyy-[m]m-[d]dT*`

#### date_format

I could not convince `date_format` to work either so I parsed "date" column myself using `substring` and `concat_ws` functions.